# get error unknown revision depency during go mod download

Tags: go, go-modules

i just clone a new repo and after it finish, i run `go mod download` and then i got error like this

```
go: github.com/micro/go-micro/v2@v2.9.1 requires
    github.com/go-acme/lego/v3@v3.4.0 requires
    github.com/google/go-querystring@v1.0.0: reading github.com/google/go-querystring/go.mod at revision v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
```

i tried to install them one by one but still had the issue, i have been read this issue and di what they said there https://github.com/micro/go-micro/issues/858, but not resolve my case here
is that any way to solve this? i have been all day to figure out this

thid id my `go env`:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/mynamehere/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/mynamehere/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/mynamehere/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="direct"
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOSUMDB="off"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/mynamehere/go/src/my-project/go.mod" // here the one got error
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build994588020=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617473/3025289

Answer (score 0):

The go modules aren't activated.

You have to execute `export GO111MODULE="on"` to get the command working.
But this has been already answered in the referenced GitHub issue.