# Installing private Go module: unknown revision error

Tags: git, go, github

I have a private Go repo at `https://github.com/myorg/myrepo` that is used by another Go repo and defined in `go.mod`.

When I try to run `$ go mod tidy` to download all the dependencies, it returns me the following error:

```
go: github.com/myorg/myrepo@v0.10.1: reading github.com/myorg/myrepo/go.mod at revision v0.10.1: unknown revision v0.10.1
```

The same thing happens when I try to "go get" this module.

**What have I tried so far?**

- Set my git config to use SSH: `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/`
- Set the `GOPRIVATE` env var: `export GOPRIVATE=github.com/myorg/*`
  Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501039/4927751

I have been stuck with this for a day now and would highly appreciate if someone can suggest me ways to fix this.

Comment: maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617473/3025289

Answer (score 4):

Finally resolved this thanks to a colleague.

**Issue**: Local module caching in Go - not sure how its managed internally by the `go` tool.

**Solution**:

1. Delete the `($GOPATH)/pkg/mod/cache` repo.
2. Reinstall the dependencies.

Comment: You can also use the command ```go clean -modcache``` and that will clear the mod cache repository as well. 

Reference:
https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-go-clean--modcache

Answer (score 0):

try setting all others env vars too.

```
export GONOSUMDB="github.com/myorg"
export GONOPROXY="github.com/myorg"
export GOPRIVATE="github.com/myorg"
```

Comment: Already did set them but gives the same error.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. I figured it out eventually. :)

Answer (score 0):

it almost correct.

```
git config --global \
  url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf \
  "https://github.com"
go mod download
```

GITHUB_TOKEN - is the [GitHub Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also tried using the Access Token but it didn't work for me.

Comment: show how did you that? it works for everyone

Comment: The solution that worked for me can be found above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609901/4927751