# golang unknown revision module/vX.Y.Z and importing package properly

Tags: go

I have a golang application structure like this:

```
.
├── calc
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── main.go
│   └── Makefile
├── go.mod
├── LICENSE
├── num
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── num.go
└── README.md
```

Where calc is an "application" where I'm importing the num package to add 2 numbers.

**calc/go.mod**

```
go 1.15

require github.com/github_username/goapp/num v0.2.1
```

num/go.mod

```
module github.com/github_username/goapp/num/v0.2.1

go 1.15
```

**go.mod**

```
module github.com/github_username/goapp/v0.2.1

go 1.15
```

When in /calc, and I run `go run main.go`, I get the following:

*go: github.com/github_username/goapp/num@v0.2.1: reading github.com/github_username/goapp/num/num/go.mod at revision num/v0.2.1: unknown revision num/v0.2.1*

What am I doing wrong? The github repo has the annotated tags.

For further context, I'm mimicking a production setup where we have six different mini golang services in folders such as calc, calc2, etc. where each "calc" service has a go.mod file.

Comment: Hi! You don't need go.mod inside of all those folders. Just the root one.

Comment: Thanks, normally that makes sense, just added some more context

Comment: Alright, but I am not sure if I am getting it right. Anyway, `go mod edit -replace` might do what you need. With this, you can say that one particular module will be replaced by a folder (or even another repository). But again, `go.mod` inside of `go.mod` does make much sense.

Comment: maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617473/3025289

Answer (score 0):

> module github.com/github_username/goapp/num/v0.2.1

Is nonsense. The semver version tag "v0.2.1" does not belong into the module name.
(Note that for major versions > 1, e.g. 4.3.1, the *major* version becomes part of the name like in `module github.com/user/proj/folder/v4`).

And one more: There are no source code belonging to the root go.mod so this module makes no sense whatsoever.

You *really* should not make that many modules.

Comment: Ok, thanks the golang dep management story is a bit new to my team.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with private repositories?

if yes, then you need to configure OAuth authentication:

```sh
export GITHUB_TOKEN=MY_GITHUB_TOKEN

git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Now, if you don't have the necessity to use private repositories!

Turn your repositories to the public that will solve the problem too.