# unknown revision go project

Tags: go, gitlab, grpc-go

I am getting following  error when I am trying to do to install a go package for example

`go get github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`

and in I am getting this error.  my project is in gitlab private repo and connected with ssh.

`go: gitlab.com/project-wide/proj-src/services/common@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 requires gitlab.com/project-wide/proj-src/services/event@v0.0.2: reading gitlab.com/project-wide/proj-src/services/event/services/event/go.mod at revision services/event/v0.0.2: unknown revision services/event/v0.0.2`

Comment: which go version are you using?
could you try to clean the cache with this? `go clean -cache -modcache` 
and see what happens when you get the modules again

Comment: @germanio I am using 1.15 .

Comment: could you add your go.mod to the question? or at least the part that references these modules

Comment: @germanio done updated. kindly have a look

Comment: how about this one? `gitlab.com/project-wide/proj-src/services/common`
can't reproduce it locally :thinking:

Comment: @germanio what could be possible reason of this error ?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it, but I think the ssh stuff may be the reason, have you checked this question/answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503167/go-build-cant-find-a-revision