# Why does go get fail with "invalid version: unknown revision"?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get

I published an update to a Go module, bumping the version to v1.1.0. I created a tag named `v1.1.0` and pushed the tag to GitHub.

https://github.com/depp/bytesize/releases/tag/v1.1.0

However, I cannot use this package in my other projects. I get an error that says, "invalid version: unknown revision v1.1.0". I don't know why the revision is "unknown", since it's tagged.

```
$ go get github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0                    
go: downloading github.com/depp/bytesize v1.1.0
go get github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0: github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0: verifying module: github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0: 410 Gone
    server response: not found: github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0: invalid version: unknown revision v1.1.0
[Exit: 1]
```

Comment: export GOPRIVATE=github.com/depp

Comment: It’s not a private module.

Comment: maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617473/3025289

Answer (score 27):

The tag was pushed after invoking `go get` once, which poisoned the Go module proxy cache.

From https://proxy.golang.org/:

> Note that if someone requested the version before the tag was pushed, it may take up to 30 minutes for the mirror's cache to expire and fresh data about the version to become available.

The way to work around this before the cache expires is to use the `GOPRIVATE` environment variable to instruct `go get` to fetch this module directly, bypassing the cache.

From https://golang.org/cmd/go/:

> GOPRIVATE, GONOPROXY, GONOSUMDB
>
> Comma-separated list of glob patterns (in the syntax of Go's path.Match)
> of module path prefixes that should always be fetched directly
> or that should not be compared against the checksum database.

The workaround is:

```
$ GOPRIVATE=github.com/depp/bytesize go get github.com/depp/bytesize@v1.1.0
```

Note that if you are already using GOPRIVATE, you will want to add modules rather than overriding the value completely.

Comment: Finally, a real answer. So many bs written by other people in over 9000 issues on this.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
export GOSUMDB=off
```

It also works for me for the error:

```
verifying module: invalid GOSUMDB: malformed verifier id
```

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotal evidence at best, but updating the go.mod file directly and running `go mod tidy` worked for me when none of the other answers did.

```
➜  cli git:(main) ✗ go get github.com/opencamp-hq/core@0.2.3
go: github.com/opencamp-hq/core@0.2.3: invalid version: unknown revision 0.2.3
➜  cli git:(main) ✗ GOPRIVATE=github.com/opencamp-hq/core go get github.com/opencamp-hq/core@0.2.3
go: github.com/opencamp-hq/core@0.2.3: invalid version: unknown revision 0.2.3
➜  cli git:(main) ✗ GOSUMDB=off go get github.com/opencamp-hq/core@0.2.3 
go: github.com/opencamp-hq/core@0.2.3: invalid version: unknown revision 0.2.3

... edited go.mod ...
➜  cli git:(main) ✗ go mod tidy
go: downloading github.com/opencamp-hq/core v0.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

For Chinese, maybe we can run :(

`export GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"`