# Go: how to remove a module from sumsdb

Tags: go, go-modules

I made a mistake described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120129/how-go-manage-its-central-repository).   Unfortunately that question is wrongly closed as "duplicate", and the proposed question is actually **not** same as mime.

Let me rephrase my question in another way: as a module author, how can I remove a module from Go's "sumsdb" so that mistake like described can be fixed.

Original question pasted below for reference.

---

**EDIT**: this question was closed by moderator, but it is NOT answered by the given uri, which gives a different error message:

[Why does go get fail with "invalid version: unknown revision"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678203/why-does-go-get-fail-with-invalid-version-unknown-revision)

I'll rephrase my questions:

I removed tag `v1.0.0` from a commit, and tagged **another** commit. Now I found that the repository is not usable anymore.   To verify: you may just do the following:

1. Clone https://github.com/xrfang/hap
2. cd into the `example` directory, then run `go build .`

This problem not only happens on my PC, but on anyone trying to use the above repo.

I wonder if the problem will disappear over time (as cache expires?) or I have to do something?  If it will heal itself, I wonder how long is the cache valid time?  If not, I would like to know how to fix that.  I hope not using things like GOPRIVATE, as this repo is going to be public (open source).

### original post:

I write a http argument parsing tool, and put it at `github.com/xrfang/hap`.  The git log is:

```
* d8cee08 2022-02-14 | implemented http.Handler interface (HEAD -> master, tag: v1.0.0, origin/master, origin/HEAD) [xrfang]
* 171dc29 2022-02-10 | updated go.mod for example [xrfang]
* d2cea3c 2022-02-09 | added example [xrfang]
* 202d959 2022-02-09 | bug fix in error handling [xrfang]
* ... ...
```

Problem is, previouly, I tagged commit `d2cea3c` as **v1.0.0**. Later I found it not optimal and added some new code.  The new code is **NOT** compatible with v1.0.0,  so I *should* make it v2.0.0. However, as this tool is newly written and I am the only user. I think it is stupid to make it v2.0.0.   So I just removed and retagged v1.0.0 to the latest commit `d8cee08`.

The problem is, go complained that the version is not "authentic". I then removed go.sum, and did `go clean -modcache`, `go get -u`, `go mod tidy`, to no avail.  The last try is:

```
$ go get -u
# example
./main.go:30:11: at.Init undefined (type apiTest has no field or method Init)
./main.go:39:2: undefined: hap.Register
```

My questions are:

1. How does Go manage its repository?  I previously found that after I updated my module and push it to github, the example often fail to compile, unless I use `replace` in go.mod, or just wait for a while (e.g. 30 minute).   It seems that there is a central "look up table" which is updated periodically and hence oftem lags behind while modules update?
2. How to fix my current problem of a re-tagged version?

Comment: Well, you bitched it up. You now either have to live with GOPROVATE or publish (at least) v1.1.0. Note: If you are the only user I think it might be ok to have v1.1.0 as the "first" released version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your understanding is correct as also described in the question you linked.
2. Either

- Publish v2.0.0
- Live with GOPRIVATE
- Publish v1.1.0

Comment: I published v1.0.1 with only an added new-line in README.md