# Private Go projects and GOPATH beyond go 1.13

Tags: go

My project depends on some private Go projects that are not go-gettable. Previously I just put then in the GOPATH at proper places (e.g., `$GOPATH/src/mycompany/mylib/lib.go`), and life was good. I.e., I don't need to apply any fancy techy hacks in,

[Go modules, private repos and gopath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516358/go-modules-private-repos-and-gopath)

and I am able to get my job done.

Now, with go beyond 1.13, is there still any low tech solution, as simple as putting it at proper place under GOPATH to such problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does the go.mod replace directive not do what you want?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem

Comment: To give the example from the docs, `replace example.com/me/goodbye => ../goodbye`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with the `$GOPATH` way, then this is still working on **go1.14.1**:

You can put both projects (not using gomodules) inside your GOPATH:

1. Project `foo` is under `GOPATH/src/foo/`
2. Project, our lib, `greeting` is under `GOPATH/src/myfancycompany/greeting/`

Our goal is that `foo` will import `greeting`.

Then `foo/main.go` will look like this:

```
package main

import "myfancycompany/greeting"

func main() {
    println("How to greet?")

    greeting.English()
}
```

And our lib `myfancycompany/greeting/greeter.go` will look like this:

```
package greeting

func English() {
    println("hi, i am boo")
}
```

Then `go build main.go` and run it `./main`:

```
~/go/src/foo$ ./main
How to greet?
hi, i am boo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fabem, that's the exact low-tech method that I'm looking for! and thanks for the working example too. Now I just need to go about and figure out why my setting is not working, but that should be minor issues. Thanks again!!!