# Can't import local project from other project: cannot find module providing package <package_name>

Tags: go, import, goland

I have a project I am working on named `project1`.
Couple of months ago I worked on `project2` which contains package named `engine` and I want to use it inside `project1`.
These projects are local so I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511866) how to import local projects and tried it but received an error:

```
Cannot resolve file `project2`
```

One interesting thing is that when I type the name of `project2` in the `import(..)` section, Goland identify it as module but after I press on it I received the error that it can't be resolve.

With Goland I have an option to run `sync packages of 'project1'` but when I pressed on it I also received an error:

```
project1/pkg/utils imports
    project2: cannot find module providing package project2
```

I also tried to create `vendor` folder in `project1` and copy-paste the whole `project2` beneath the `vendor` folder but it still didn't help.

Any idea why it doesn't being resolve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both of your projects under your `$GOPATH`, you can check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130164/private-go-projects-and-gopath-beyond-go-1-13/61130567#61130567) for importing projects.

**EDIT:**
If you are using `go modules` and want to import local modules, then you can make use of the `replace` directive.
So, basically you have to add in your `go.mod` of your `Project1` these lines:

```
require /$module-name-project2/$package-name v0.0.0

replace $module-name-project2/$package-name => ../$localpath-to-project2
```

More info [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)

A quick example (both my projects are outside of `$GOPATH` and using `go modules`):

1. `Project1` is located under `.../go-experiments/project1`

`main.go`:

```
package main

import "go-experiments/project2/greeting"

func main() {
    println("How to greet?")

    greeting.English()
}
```

`go.mod`:

```
module go-experiments/project1

require go-experiments/project2/greeting v0.0.0

replace go-experiments/project2/greeting => ../project2

go 1.14
```

1. `Project2` is located under `.../go-experiments/project2`
   `greeter.go`:

```
package greeting

func English() {
   println("hi, i am boo")
}
```

`go.mod`:

```
module go-experiments/project2

go 1.14
```

Comment: I already did it `import "project2"` but it wrote be the errors that I wrote on the question

Comment: Are you using gomodules?

Comment: I have edited my answer - check it out if this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer! It worked. I just needed to add `project2/engine v0.0.0` to `require` and add `replace project2/engine => ../project2` to `go.mod` and now it recognized it.

Comment: Only problem I see here is that this will create restrictions on how code is structured by anyone who wants to re-use the module created by you. From go1.13 and above we can re-use local file locations as goproxy. But, unfortunately there is no proper tooling to use the same right now.